# Distorted .obj Export

Tags: export

Whenever I export a mesh, wich is just a tiny bit complex from blender to an .obj file, some parts of the mesh are ending up wierdly distorted. The only solution I found is to check "triangulate faces" at the export options.
But shouldn't it work without that?

The mesh in blender:
[image: The mesh in Blender:]

The mesh in Marmoset Toolbag:
[image: The mesh in Marmoset Toolbag]

Here the .blend file:
https://www.mediafire.com/folder/b8xga0wnsmwew/blender

In other programs, the same.

Any help is appriciated
Nightfox3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your mesh are Ngons; Blender can process and show them correctly but once exported you get unexpected results because they are treated in a different way by another program.

This is what model looks like:

[image: original model screenshots]

The reason why it worked with *Triangulate faces* checked is because there were no Ngons any more, all them were converted to tris. You can use this way, however you won't be able to control *how* it will triangulate faces.

Hence I suggest to start with changed topology of the model (note: it may be a bit complex to redo for all the model, however it will save time further on):

[image: screenshot of better topology of the model]

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is that most render engines can only render tris, Cycles included. It could have to do with the way Toolbag imports...